# Iterate through Inner Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

im a beginner in Python. im practicing a use case to get the final score of the student that are stored in dictionaries. COuld you please guide me is there a way to simplify this?

```
 ScoreCard = {'Antony':{'maths':99,'english':33, 'science':100},'Jeff':{'maths':45,'english':99, 'science':73},
        'Mark':{'maths':77,'english':80, 'science':86}}

def sumofMarks(MarkList):
    SumMark = 0
    for k, v in MarkList.items():
        SumMark = SumMark + v
    return SumMark
        
def getMarks(Score, student):
    for k,v in Score.items():
        if student in Score.keys():
            newdic = Score[student]
            finalScore = sumofMarks(newdic)
            print("Final Score of:", student)
            return finalScore
        else:
            print("Student Not found in registry !")
            break            

getMarks(ScoreCard,'Jeff')
```

Comment: For code review, see [codereview.se]. This is too broad for SO. See [ask] for tips on asking a good SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `values()` to get all values of dictionary and `sum()` to get sum of them:

```py
ScoreCard = {'Antony': {'maths': 99, 'english': 33, 'science': 100},
             'Jeff': {'maths': 45, 'english': 99, 'science': 73},
             'Mark': {'maths': 77, 'english': 80, 'science': 86}}

def getMarks(Score, student):
    if student in Score:
        print(sum(Score[student].values()))
    else:
        print('Student not found')

getMarks(ScoreCard, 'Jeff')
# 217
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ScoreCard = {'Antony':{'maths':99,'english':33, 'science':100},'Jeff':{'maths':45,'english':99, 'science':73},
        'Mark':{'maths':77,'english':80, 'science':86}}
name = "Jeff"
if name in ScoreCard.keys():
    for k,v in ScoreCard.items():
        if k==name:
            s = 0
            for k1,v1 in v.items():
                s+=v1
    print("Final Score of :",s)
else:
    print(name,"not found in registry")
```